# AngularJS pegar um dado do input que foi preenchido por um JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cep

Bom dia, sou iniciante com Web, embora eu saiba programar em outras linguagens.
A minha duvida é a seguinte, através do via cep eu peguei o algoritmo que preenche os campos de endereço através de um Javascript.

meu imput é esse:

```
input class="form-control" type="text" id="rua" ng-model="cadastro.endereco.endereco" maxlength="60"
```

o Javascript preenche o input ao digitar o cep, porém na hora de salvar, os dados que foram completados pelo js NÃO são salvos.
Apenas o CEP, Número e Complemento que foram digitados manualmente.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Obrigado.

Eu fiz assim, usei o script deste site
https://viacep.com.br/exemplo/javascript/

para bucar o endereco atravez do cep.
dai coloquei a id igual no js para preencher a aárea de texto.

input class="form-control" type="text" id="rua" ng-model="cadastro.endereco.endereco" maxlength="60"

preenche perfeitmente, acontece que na hora de salvar, os campos que foram preenchidos pelo script ficam em branco, so salvam os campos que digitei manualmente como número e complemento do endereço

Descobri que por padrão o AngularJS exige que os campos tenham alguma interação do usuário para efetuar o binding. 
Alguém sabe como faço pra forçar o binding para o campo input ou então desativar isso no angular?
obrigado.

Comment: Por que você não faz a requisição para o Via Cep pelo Angular?

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta, você poderia reformular ? eu já fiz um exemplo com esta api, da uma olhada nessa demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/9Ry6GfYqt2phUsW5iBFo?p=preview

Comment: Seu exemplo está ok. Pode colocar o exemplo da pergunta?

Comment: Eu fiz assim, usei o script deste site
https://viacep.com.br/exemplo/javascript/

para bucar o endereco atravez do cep.
dai coloquei a id igual no js para preencher a aárea de texto.

input class="form-control" type="text" id="rua" ng-model="cadastro.endereco.endereco" maxlength="60"

preenche perfeitmente, acontece que na hora de salvar, os campos que foram preenchidos pelo script ficam em branco, so salvam os campos que digitei manualmente como número e complemento do endereço

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Celso, por que você não altera este algoritmo que preenche o html, e ao invés do mesmo setor o valor para o input do DOM você não faz ele setar o valor diretamente para sua variável "cadastro.endereco.endereco" do javascript.

Isto com certeza vai solucionar seu problema.

*espero ter ajudado.*

Comment: agora aparece esse erro.
ncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

eu esqueci de dizer, estou usando o laravel 5, a variavel endereco está dentro do cadastro.js que fica dentro de controllers.

eu to apanhando que é uma beleza disso.

Comment: Então Celso não tenho conhecimento com laravel, assim não consigo te ajudar. Adicione uma tag laravel 5 para ajudamos a limitar sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

A questão é que você tem que salvar isso na sua variável que faz o *meio de campo* entre seu javascript e sua página html.

No AngularJS usamos a variável `$scope` para acessarmos ela no lado do javascript (dentro do seu controller) enquanto no lado da página temos o `ng-model`. Pela sua parte do código pude notar que você já colocou o `ng-model` na chamada da página, agora o que tens que garantir é que os atributos passados estão sendo salvos no `$scope`.

O que sugiro é que troque todas as atribuições do Javaspcript da página de exemplo para atribuições direto para `$scope` ao invés de atribuir a algum *input* por `Id`, é justamente para esse tipo de facilidade que o `AngularJS` serve. Ao invés de suas atribuições serem asim:

```
document.getElementById('rua').value=(conteudo.logradouro);
```

Elas vão ficar dessa maneira

```
$scope.rua = conteudo.logradouro;
```

E o campo de input de deveria ser como segue:

```
<input name="rua" ng-model="rua" type="text" id="rua" size="60" /></label>
```

O correto seria fazer isso para todas as variáveis manipuladas do DOM ao invés de pega-las por `ID`.

---

Você pode ler mais sobre o $scope nos links que seguem:

[Link 1](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp)

[Link 2](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, segui seu conselho, mas ainda nao deu certo.
Acontece que estou usando o Laravel 5, o arquivo cadastro.js tem a função de salvar que salva os enderecos em na variavel endereco.
Enquanto o meu script está dentro do html.
como eu estou em fase de treinamento aqui na empresa, e nunca havia visto nada disso, estou apanhando um bocado.

Comment: Qual o erro acontecendo agora?

Comment: Como o amigo comentou na resposta abaixo é desejável que você adicione todas as partes do problemas, sejam elas como tag ou na descrição. Sugiro também detalhar melhor a pergunta, para que possamos te ajudar de maneira mais eficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Troquei o `$http.get` pelo `$getJSON` e assim deu certo.

E nos inputs não precisa repetir o campo `model="cadastro.endereco.endereco"`.
Faça apenas `model="cadastro.endereco"`

Veja abaixo como ficou:

```
  <input class="form-control" ng-model="p.localidade">
  <input class="form-control" ng-model="p.uf" >
  <input class="form-control" ng-model="p.bairro" >
  <input class="form-control" ng-model="p.logradouro" >
```

```
var app = angular.module("cep");
app.controller("buscaCEPCtrl",function($scope,$http){

    $scope.buscar = function(cep){
   //$http.get('https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+cep+'/json/').success(function(data){
    $.getJSON('https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+cep+'/json/').success(function(data){
            $scope.form = data;
                $scope.resCep= false;
        }).error(function(){
            $scope.resCep= true;
        });
    };
});
```